# How do I force Twig output from my custom module, instead of from the theme?

Tags: theming, blocks

I'm new to Drupal, I create a module including block and twig.
I want to call out my twig(modules/custom/footer_block/src/templates) and store data in there when execute build() in block.

However, it output a twig from theme folder(a templates folder inside the theme folder) that's is not created by me.

How can I force to output from my module folder?

The block is using the following code.

#### footerMenu_block.php.

```
public function build(){
    return [
        '#theme' => 'footer_menu',
        '#address_title' => $this->configuration['address_title'],
        '#address_content' => $this->configuration['address_content'],
    ];
```

#### footer-menu.twig.html

```
<div>
       <h2>{{ address_title }}</h2>
       <p>{{ address_content }}</p>
 </div>
```

#### footer_block.module

```
<?php
function footer_block_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
    'footer_menu' =>
      array(
        'variables' => array(
          'address_title' => '',
          'address_content' => '',
        ),
      ),
  );
}
```

If I move the Twig to that output folder (inside theme folder), it will be unable to store my data.
If I make simple output '#markup' inside `build()` that will work fine. Therefore, other code in block should be working without problem.

I am using Drupal 8.6.x.

Comment: Sorry guys! I found out the problem, just because my templates folder put inside the src folder. they should be at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the template array key to your theme hook:

```
function footer_block_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return [
    'footer_menu' => [
      'variables' => [
        'address_title' => '',
        'address_content' => '',
      ],
      'template' => 'footer-menu',
    ],
  ];
}
```

Or try adding the block twig template suggestion as:

```
function footer_block_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return [
    'footer_menu' => [
      'template' => 'footer-menu',
      'base hook' => 'block',
    ],
  ];
}
```

Comment: I tried both of them. Unfortunately, both of them are not working for me

Comment: Your block is in the block list? Can be placed on page? Do you see theme suggestions for your block when inspecting element?

Comment: Yes mate, my page can display the block title but not including content.